# How can I close all the open file handles in a child process?

Tags: c, windows

I have two programs, let's call them `prog-1.exe` and `prog-2.exe`. `prog-1.exe` starts `prog-2.exe` using `system`. The first thing I would like to do in `prog-2.exe` is close all the open file handles that it inherited from `prog-1.exe`. This is what I have tried:

**Starting Code for `prog-2.exe`**

```
static int closeFileHandles()
{
   // From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxfsw25t.aspx
   // The _fcloseall function closes all open streams
   // except stdin, stdout, stderr
   return _fcloseall();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   // First things first...
   // Close all the inherited file handles.
   closeFileHandles();

   // Continue with the rest of the program
}
```

**Code in `prog-1.exe`**

```
FILE* in = fopen(inputFile, "r");

// ....
// ....

// Start prog-2.exe
system("prog-2.exe"); // It's in my path.

// prog-2.exe starts another process that stays in background mode
// Call this server.exe.

// Close the file.
fclose(in);
```

**Problem**

I want to delete the directory where `inputFile` is from `prog-1.exe`. I am not able to delete the directory since `server.exe` has an open handle to `inputFile` (This information is given by Windows when I try to delete the directory in Windows Explorer).

**Questions**

Am I not using `_fcloseall()` correctly?

Is `_fcloseall()` the right function to use for my purposes?

Are there any other functions/methods to close all the open file handles inherited from a parent process?

Comment: Note that __fcloseall_ does closes file handles in the _current process_ and not on other processes.

Doing what you want, the way you want, is a little more tricky, prog-2 would have to intervene with the prog-1 process and close it's handle, There _might_ be some leads here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx

Comment: _fcloseall affects C runtime streams, not Windows handles.  But why are you allowing the handles to be inherited in the first place if you're just going to close them again straight away?

Comment: @HLL I was hoping that `_fcloseall` will close all the open file handles prog-2 inherits from prog-1. I want the file handles to stay open in prog-1. I am still hoping that it is achievable. I'll take a look at the article you pointed me to. Thanks.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I am not doing anything to inherit the open file handles. I am guessing that that is side effect of using system. I want the file handles to remain open in the parent process and to be closed in the child process.

Comment: Yes, you should be using `CreateProcess` instead of `system`.  That way you can choose not to allow handle inheritance.

Comment: I should also mention that you can disable inheritance for a given handle, either when the handle is opened or by using `SetHandleInformation`.  But this is unlikely to be convenient if you're using C runtime functions for I/O.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Using `CreateProcess`, with appropriate flags, instead of `system` solved the problem. If you want to add the comment as answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported way to enumerate handles, so it is not usually practical to close all inherited handles within the subprocess.  (In principle your main process could pass the subprocess a list of handles to close, but if the main process has such a list it would be easier to disable inheritance on those handles.)

However, if you launch the subprocess using `CreateProcess` instead of `system()` you have the option to disable handle inheritance by setting `bInheritHandles` to `FALSE`.  This is the most straightforward solution in your situation.

Alternatively, if you needed to inherit only one or more specific handles (for example, in order to redirect the standard input or output) you could use `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` with [`UpdateProcThreadAttributeList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and associated functions to specify the handles you want inherited.  The attribute list can be passed to `CreateProcess` by passing a [`STARTUPINFOEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure and setting `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT` in the `dwCreationFlag` parameter.